# REST API latency on LAN

Tags: rest, networking, mobile, tcp, low-latency

I'm designing a mobile application that communicates with a laptop over LAN where minimal latency is critical, and I'd like to potentially have the host laptop receive information through a RESTful service. Is there any solid case for using lower-level communication like TCP to reduce delays?

Comment: Does your mobile device enjoy a LAN-port for such a connection -- what kind? What is your low-latency target zone -- in [ns]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the RESTful service is based on HTTP protocol that runs over TCP/IP if you need low latency you could to use UDP protocol, but should keep in mind that you can loss some packages.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what the packet loss rate looks like on local networks? I imagine it's better than over the internet; anyways packet loss isn't a deal breaker.